# No module named 'ner'

Tags: macos, python-2.7, osx-mavericks, importerror

I am getting import error on python module "ner". Here is the installation summary of the manual installation.

```
Hogwarts:pyner-master Akrita$ sudo python setup.py install
Password:
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing ner.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to ner.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to ner.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'ner.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'ner.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg
copying build/lib/.DS_Store -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
copying build/lib/ner/.DS_Store -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
copying build/lib/ner/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
copying build/lib/ner/client.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
copying build/lib/ner/exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
copying build/lib/ner/utils.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner/client.py to client.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner/exceptions.py to exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ner/utils.py to utils.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ner.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ner.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ner.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying ner.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/ner-0.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing ner-0.1-py2.7.egg
Copying ner-0.1-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Adding ner 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ner-0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for ner==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for ner==0.1
Hogwarts:pyner-master Akrita$
```

I am getting import error when I "import ner".
I tried :

```
>> import.sys
>> sys.path
```

and here it is not even showing the package I installed.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Python interface to the Stanford Named Entity Recognizer from [here](https://github.com/dat/pyner)